# Find all instances of a word in a string and display them in textbox (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a string filled with the contents of a textbox (pretty large).

I want to search through it and display all occurances of this word. In addition I need the searchresult to display some charachters in the string before and after the actual searchterm to get the context for the word.

The code below is part of a code that takes keywords from a listbox one by one using For Each.  The code displays the first occurance of a word together with the characters in front and after the word - and stop there. It will also display "no Match for: searched word" if not found.

As stated in the subject of this question - I need it to search the whole string and display all matches for a particular word together with the surrounding characters.

```vb
Where = InStr(txtScrape.Text, Search)

If Where <> 0 Then
    txtScrape.Focus()
    txtScrape.SelectionStart = Where - 10
    txtScrape.SelectionLength = Where + 50
    Result = txtScrape.SelectedText
    AllResults = AllResults + Result

Else
    AllResults = AllResults + "No Match for: " & item
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you can split the string into long sentences by special symbols, such as , : ? .
[Split(Char[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_Char___)
You can refer to the following code.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = ""
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim longStr() As String
    Dim str = TextBox3.Text
    longStr = TextBox1.Text.Split(New Char() {CChar(":"), CChar(","), CChar("."), CChar("?"), CChar("!")})
    Index = 0

    For Each TheStr In longStr
        If TheStr.Contains(str) Then
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(longStr(Index) & vbCrLf)
        End If
        Index = Index + 1
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    TextBox1.Text = "....."

End Sub
End Class
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Dim ArrStr() As String
Dim Index As Integer
Dim TheStr As String
Dim MatchFound As Boolean 
MatchFound = False
ArrStr = Split(txtScrape.text," ")
Index = 1
For Each TheStr In ArrStr
  If TheStr = Search Then
    Console.WriteLine(Index)
    MatchFound = True
  End If
  Index = Index + 1
Next
Console.WriteLine(MatchFound)
```

Inside the If statement you will get the index there. And MatchFound is the Boolean value if match found.